# How do I configure ESLint to not support IE?

Tags: ecmascript-6, eslint, eslintrc, browser-support

I am not supporting IE on a project I am working on - how do I tell that to ESLINT?

Currently I'm getting a red squiggly line for trying to use `Map.values()` - here's the error:

`Map.values() is not supported in IE 11 - eslint(compat/compat)` (compat/compat links to https://github.com/amilajack/eslint-plugin-compat/blob/main/docs/rules/compat.md)